# How to align two TextViews horizontally in ConstraintLayout without overlap?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to align two TextViews horizontally like so: 
[image: Text A Short Correct]
My current layout works fine when Text A is short. However things break when a long string is set for textA, like the following. Text A and Text B are overlapping even though the end of Text A is constrained to the start of Text B.
[image: Text A Long Overlapping]

Here is how it should look when Text A is very long.
[image: Text A Long Correct]

---

**Current XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_background"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` attribute to your `textA` `TextView` to enforce constraints while having the width set to `wrap_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_background"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text A"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That's just perfect. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_background"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Text A"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textB"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textB"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Text B"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textA"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This does work, but it sort of defeats the point of ConstraintLayout, which is to have a flattened layout for better performance, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the second textview `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textA"` to move to the right of textview A.
Change the textB as below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Text B"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textA" />
```

Comment: Yes madam. Did u try?